# Zend Studio & GitHub can pull from repository but not push

Tags: github, zend-studio

I followed directions from [this](http://www.thomasweidner.com/flatpress/2011/04/03/using-git-with-zend-studio/) page. Everyting seems to work. 
So in short what I did.

Created a repository in GitHub called 'myrepository'
Imported the repository successfully into Zend framework.
In Zend Studio went to `preferences` -> `general` -> `network connections` -> `ssh2` -> `key management` -> `Generate SSH key`. I then copied and pasted the key into my account on github.

If I create a file in GitHub and go back to Zend Framework to pull it in, it actually works. If I do it the other way around though creating a file in ZF and then trying to push it, it doesn't show up in my repository in GitHub. Can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't realise I needed to create a local repository first in order to properly set up ZS with EGit.

I Followed the tutorial on the [EGit gettting started page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide/Getting_Started), and then went back to the instructions on [EGit with GitHub instructions](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#GitHub_Tutorial). This made Nils Werner's comment make sense where you simply choose the connection method on your GitHub account and configure EGit accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, those instructions use the `https` method while you are trying to set up the `ssh` method...

You either don't need to set up your ssh keys or you need to use the `git@github.com...` URL.

Comment: Confusing since the instructions mention the ssh key as first step, and then importing with the HTTP stuff as second step. Are the instructions plain wrong then?

Comment: I can confirm that I can import the project using https related login data while the ssh key is deleted. The HTML/SSH thing seems to besides the issue though since the problem persists after https only method.